# variable factors in Simulimk

Tags: matlab, signal-analysis, simulink

In my simulation of an equation in Simulink, I need to have variable factors the same as shown in following picture but Simulink doesn't accept that. how I can solve this problem?

[image: my simulation diagrams]

Comment: What do you mean as "variable"? You want to.change them during simulation or just parametrize them?

Comment: If you define m c and k as variables in your matlab environment you can just type 1/m, c and k in the corresponding fields